# ASP.NET MVC Web Application with SQL Azure (To Do List Tutorial) -- error when deploying to production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure-sql-database

I'm working on the following tutorial in the Windows Azure website:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-app-with-sql-azure/

(also: go to windowsazure.com, click on the "Develop" heading, click on ".Net" under languages, under "Create Your First Application" -- click on ASP.NET MVC Web Application with SQL Azure)

I can run the application in the Windows Azure emulation environment on my development machine.  If I change the connection strings to the ***production database***, the app ***works*** in the local development environment.

However, when I deploy the application to Azure, I get an error message:  "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." This appears within a rendered page, so I think the request is getting to ASP.NET.

I believe the problem I'm having is with allowing the production app on Azure to connect to the SQL Azure database.

I believe it is a firewall issue, but haven't been able to determine what the IP range needs to be.  (I previously thought the problem would be with me running VS 2010 in a 32 bit environment, with Windows Azure as a 64 bit environment, but we deployed the sample app from a 64 bit environment and had the same issue).  For additional details, here's my previous posting on MSDN to a previous inquiry on the same issue:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/23afb5e3-e2ee-4444-aabb-7001ae6c6e6a/#af5284c0-ef4b-4193-b912-d4b7adfb5d21

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.  I really want this sample app to work!

Comment: Have you try `<customErrors mode="Off" />` to get the error description?

Answer (score 1):

Update:  Got the tutorial to work on a different computer and fresh 64 bit configuration, pointing to a different data center.

I got my hands on a new laptop with 64bit Windows 7 Home Premium , and installed Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, all of the most recent Azure and MVC SDKs.  Seems like what I thought was a firewall issue, could have possibly been issues with database connectivity at the North Central data center.  (I'm speculating, and will still need to test my original configuration against the South Central data center to see if this is actually the case.  But, the North Central data center was not an available choice for hosting a SQL Azure database (3 month subscription), and here's a link to a discussion of this on another thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/ssdsgetstarted/thread/7b181eef-ccd1-4090-80d1-0853059d166f

As mentioned above, the checkbox "Allow other Windows Azure services to access this server" needs to be checked, and both the service and the database need to be located in the same Windows Azure data center.

Answer (score 0):

[image]As @veblock suggest, you may try switching off the custom errors to see the actual error.

Meanwhile, the "IP range" that you seek for enabling firewall rule for your role is just a checkbox away:

You just need to check that "Allow other Windows Azure services to access this server" checkbox. The entry "Microsoft Services" with IP range of "0.0.0.0 - 0.0.0.0" will be automatically added. This is an internal entry and Microsoft keeps track of their own IP ranges, so that any Windows Azure data center will be able to access this SQL Azure Server.

But, yes, you can also check the real error message, by either Remote Desktopping to the instance, or by disabling the custom errors. There is a small chance that the ASP.NET MVC is also not fully installed in the Azure Instance. The easiest way to eliminate this problem would be by right clicking on the web application project and select "Add deployable dependencies", then chose ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I have also hit this issues and spent several hours to debug what was going on since everything worked as expected in the Emulator, but won't work in production. After I have moved my hosted service and the database server to be in the same region, the problem went away.

In the original sample, it was also noted that it was important to ensure both are in the same region, but it mentioned due to performance reasons only, but for me it won't work at all.

"
IMPORTANT: Pick the same region that you choose earlier when deploying your application. This will give you the best performance. 
"